# How can I get a model query like this in SEQUALIZE? I want to add a column with a default value

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, reactjs, sequelize.js

How can I get a model query in SEQUALIZE like that one?

```
SELECT existingColumn, ‘example’ AS example FROM mytable
```

So the result will be the existingColumn with its values, and an extra example column with a value equals example in every row.

Comment: Have you tried that yet?

Comment: I would like to use model querying.